# Asp.net core bodyUsed is false

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, aurelia

I'm working with [aurelia](http://aurelia.io) 
and asp.net core. The problem I've is that when I try to fetch data with aurelia:

```
test() {
    this.http.fetch('values', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            // More options
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        })
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "admin, user")]
public IActionResult Values()
{
  return Json("value");
}
```

I receive this in my console:

```
bodyUsed:false
status: 200
```

So why do I not receive a body?

Comment: Can you confirm if your request hit `Values` method?

Answer (score 1):

The MDN says:

> The bodyUsed read-only property of the Body mixin contains a Boolean that indicates whether the body has been read yet.

So, you have to call `blob()`, `json()` or another body function and then the property `bodyUsed` should become `true`;

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/bodyUsed